# Getting the first item item in a many-to-many relation in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have two models in Django linked together by ManyToMany relation like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person)
```

I need to get the main person in the group which is the first person in the group. How can I get the first person?

Here's how I'm adding members:

```
grp = Group.objects.create(name="Group 1")
grp.save()
prs = Person.objects.create(name="Tom")
grp.members.add(prs) #This is the main person of the group.
prs = Person.objects.create(name="Dick")
grp.members.add(prs)
prs = Person.objects.create(name="Harry")
grp.members.add(prs)
```

I don't think I need any additional columns as the id of the table `group_members` is a running sequence right.

If I try to fetch the main member of the group through `Group.objects.get(id=1).members[0]` then Django says that the manager is not indexable.

If I try this `Group.objects.get(id=1).members.all().order_by('id')[0]`, I get the member with the lowest id in the `Person` table.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to determine who is the "first" person in the group? ID? Alphabetically?

Comment: The one with the lowest `id` in the table `group_members`. Objects are never deleted from this table so the main member will always be the same for a group.

Comment: Alex Gaynor's answer is correct. You'd need to add an additional field to order by the group, as the ID column isn't guaranteed to be sequential for the group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django doesn't pay attention to the order of the calls to `add`. The implicit table Django has for the relationship is something like the following if it was a Django model:

```
class GroupMembers(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

Obviously, there's nothing there about an "order" or which you should come first. By default, it will probably do as you describe and return the lowest pk, but that's just because it has nothing else to go off of.

If you want to enforce an order, you'll have to use a through table. Basically, instead of letting Django create that implicit model, you create it yourself. Then, you'll add a field like `order` to dictate the order:

```
class GroupMembers(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Then, you tell Django to use this model for the relationship, instead:

```
class GroupMembers(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, through='GroupMembers')
```

Now, when you add your members, you can't use `add` anymore, because additional information is need to complete the relationship. Instead, you must use the through model:

```
prs = Person.objects.create(name="Tom")
GroupMembers.objects.create(person=prs, group=grp, order=1)
prs = Person.objects.create(name="Dick")
GroupMembers.objects.create(person=prs, group=grp, order=2)
prs = Person.objects.create(name="Harry")
GroupMembers.objects.create(person=prs, group=grp, order=3)
```

Then, just use:

```
Group.objects.get(id=1).members.all()[0]
```

Alternatively, you could simply add a `BooleanField` to specify which is the main user:

```
class GroupMembers(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    is_main_user = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Then, add "Tom" like:

```
prs = Person.objects.create(name="Tom")
GroupMembers.objects.create(person=prs, group=grp, is_main_user=True)
```

And finally, retrieve "Tom" via:

```
Group.objects.get(id=1).members.filter(is_main_user=True)[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You were pretty close:

```
Group.objects.get(id=1).members.all()[0]
```

(But as Alex Gaynor says in his answer, for predictable behaviour you need a proper field to sort on)

Comment: I had a look at the table whcih contains the relationship i.e. `group_persons` (I think),  in the database and it had an `id` column apart from the `group_id` and `person_id`. Since this is a running sequence, can't I get the item with the lowest `id`. The example that you gave: wouldn't that return me the first object in the set but the set wouldn't be ordered and thereby incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the second "objects" (does that even work?) Just `members.all()`.

Answer (score 2):

Relational database don't have any notion of ordering, by default. There's no such thing as "first". You need to add an explicit "order" field which keeps the order, and order by it.

Answer (score 0):

to reliably keep a record of who is the "main" person in a group, you may want to have a look at using a [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table to keep this metadata